# Displace modifier - undesired artifacts in texture

Tags: uv, displacement

I'm creating a model that I want to later print in 3D. I am using a *Displace* modifier after a *Multiresolution* modifier to add a patern to some faces (using a vèrtex group plus displace on the Y axis to ensure that only the desired areas are displaced).

[image]

However, when it is rendered, in the **lower face** that appears as selected in the UV map shown above, two undesired effects appear:

- an **horitzontal noise**, that I think it might be the full texture that is rotated 90 degrees and compressed to cover the whole face.
- some **light displacement outside the vertex group**, as you can see in a face in the back part of the model

[image]

I have recreated the materials and textures and ensured that there's only one UV map. I've also removed the displacement map and applied the texture as a verification, and in this case the object is properly textured, as you can see below:

[image]

... aaand, just before pressing the *post* button, it occurred to me that the multiresolution  could be causing a distortion due to the shared edge at 45°. I applied the modifier and inspected the generated faces. Indeed the generated subdivisions distorted the UV mapping, and also **the vèrtex group spreaded towards the backward faces**, creating the undesired displacement. So I modified the faces to ensure that all the edges are parallel. The displacement has **improved a lot**, but still there's an light, horitzontal undesired artifact...

[image]

I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone have some idea of what might be happening? Thanks!

---------------- ANSWER ------------------
I've marked the response below as an answer. I wanted however to summarise the things I've done to fix my problem:

1. I modified the mesh to have a more *square* faces. When I first improved the appearance of the displacement, I just removed the oblique edge and created a square at the righ-low corner. But was not enough to get rid of the artifacts shown in the screenshot. However, after seeing the answer below, I added some edge loops (3 to be precise) and then the displacement worked well.
2. I then applied the multiresolution modifier, and corrected the vèrtex group to which the displacement is applied, and got rid of the displacement noise in the back faces.
   [image]

Comment: Hmm. Weird. Setting the displace mod to rgb-xyz fixed the problem for me. Try playing around with the displacement settings a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displacement to work well all the faces should be equal size squares.

[image]

[image]